# Issue with \usepackage{floatrow} . please help

Tags: floatrow

All, I used to run my my `.tex` code without any problem until this week where I started getting error

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: File `floatrow.sty' not found
> ```

with the package `\usepackage{floatrow}`

I dont see what I am doing wrong.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

**\usepackage{floatrow}**
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

%\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}   % to change margins
%\usepackage{titling}             % Uncomment both to   
\setlength{\droptitle}{-2cm}     % change title position 
%\author{Fran}
%\geometry{top=20mm}
\pretitle{\begingroup\centering\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\endgroup}


\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[top=1in,left=0.9in,right=0.9in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[top=0.45in,left=0.9in,right=0.9in,bottom=0.45in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\definecolor{tableShade}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\bigstrutjot{3pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{flushleft}
\fontsize{20}{14}\selectfont
  \textbf{\@title}

\end{flushleft}\egroup
}
\makeatother


%https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Please help where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is your distribution?